# sass mixin + it-self as consecutive tag?

Tags: css, sass, mixins, scss-mixins

I'm looking for a way to make an equivalent to `.bloc + .bloc` or `.article + .article` but directly from a mixin `bloc-article()` :

```
@mixin bloc-article() {

    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-top: 50px;

    & + "bloc-article()" { // is there a "$this"-like to make an equivalent to `.bloc + .bloc` or `.article + .article` here ?
        border-top: 1px solid red;
    }
}

.bloc {
    @include bloc-article();
}

.article {
    @include bloc-article();
}
```

is there a "$this"-like to make an equivalent to `.bloc + .bloc` or `.article + .article` directly from the mixin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your mixin with an `& + &` selector:

```
@mixin bloc-article() {
  // …

  & + & {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

Which compiles from:

```
.article {
  @include bloc-article();
}
```

to:

```css
.article + .article {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

---

Here, the Sass *parent selector* is the `$this` you are looking for.

From the [docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector):

> The parent selector, &, is a special selector invented by Sass that’s used in nested selectors to refer to the outer selector. It makes it possible to re-use the outer selector in more complex ways, like adding a pseudo-class or adding a selector before the parent.